# Tangent to Ellipse

Tags: conic-sections, implicit-differentiation

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. Not quite sure how to get at it. I've tried finding the derivative of the equation and using point slope form but cant get it to look like the defined tangent line. Also, a and b are both constants.

Show that $(x_0,y_0)$ is the point at which

$$\frac{x_0}{a^2}x + \frac{y_0}{b^2}y = 1$$

is tangent to the curve

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$

Answer (score 3):

Well, the *basic* assumption must be that the given point is on the ellipse, which means

$$\frac{x_0^2}{a^2}+\frac{y_0^2}{b^2}=1\iff x_0^2b^2+y_0^2a^2=a^2b^2$$

Now the slope of tangent line at *any* point on the ellipse is given by the value of the derivative at the point, so differentiating implicitly the ellipse's equation:

$$\frac{2x}{a^2}dx+\frac{2y}{b^2}dy=0\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\frac xy$$

which is the slope of the given line at the given point...

Comment: It might be better to use the standard notation for implicit differentiation: $(2x/a^2) + (2y/b^2)(dy/dx)=0$. After all, we assume that $y=y(x)$ satisfies the question and then differentiate w.r.t. $x$. Strictly speaking, you have found the exterior derivative.

Comment: For me the "standard" way is what I wrote. I really should check this since I'm no sure whether my standard is the *actual* general standard

Comment: Here's a link: bit.ly/1crgZ7x The left hand side is most certainly a differential one-form, and is the exterior derivative of the OP's function. I often use the technique "backwards", start with a one-form and get a gradient field. See the link for what I know as the "standard" way.

Comment: **+1** Nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

We need to show that (1) $(x_0,y_0)$ lies on the lines and that (2) the slope of the line is $f'(x_0)$.

The first condition is obvious, since substituting $(x_0,y_0)$ in for $(x,y)$ yields
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1
$$
which is true because $(x_0,y_0)$ lies on the ellipse.

To find the slope, we differentiate implicitly with respect to $x$. This yields

$$
\frac{2x}{a^2}+(\frac{2y}{b^2})(\frac{dy}{dx})=0
$$
So $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{xb^2}{ya^2}$.
But the slope of the given line is $-\frac{x_0b^2}{y_0a^2}$, which is exactly the slope of the tangent line at the point $(x_0,y_0)$, so this line is the equation of the tangent line at $(x_0,y_0)$.